# How to union tables into a new table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have a table as following:

```
id col1 col2 col3 type
1  12   12   23   1
2  23   33   1    0 
3  333  2    21   1
.....
```

I try to select 1% sample of where type=1 and all the data where type=0, I wrote the code as following:

```
 create table tbl2(
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE type=1 AND RAND() <= 0.01
    UNION
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE type =0 
    );
```

It ends up as an error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
WHERE type =0
)' at line 3
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The query and the error message do not match.

Comment: @yerpcube that makes me wonder if some framework is generating the query. I hope that's the case and mysql isn't compiled with this parsing anomaly.

Comment: Try without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just loaded this into MySQL 5.5.37 on my Windows Laptop

```
use test
drop table if exists tbl1;
create table tbl1
(id int not null,
col1 int not null,
col2 int not null,
col3 int not null,
type int not null);
insert into tbl1 values
(1,  12,   12,   23,   1),
(2,  23,   33,   1,    0), 
(3,  333,  2,    21,   1);
```

Then, I tried out the query

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM tbl1
    -> WHERE type=1 AND RAND() <= 0.01
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT *
    -> FROM tbl1
    -> WHERE type =0 ;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | type |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  2 |   23 |   33 |    1 |    0 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Your syntax is just fine !!!**

Your error message has `UNION SELECT * SELECT *` as the problem. Take a closer look at the message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
SELECT * 
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
WHERE type =0
)' at line 3
```

I see `SELECT *` twice and a trailing right parenthesis that you did not type in the query.

If your version of MySQL consistently produces that error message, then you must have a bug within in the Query Parser. You may need to upgrade MySQL as a last resort.

## SUGGESTION

Your `CREATE TABLE` will not have any indexes.

Try creating the table with indexes and loading afterwards

```
create table tbl2 like tbl1;
insert into tbl2
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE type=1 AND RAND() <= 0.01
    UNION
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE type =0 
;
```

Comment: I concur: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf20a2/2

Comment: Thx. Now... I found my query is fine...My problem is actually I want to create a new table based on the query I wrote. The create does not work.